# has anyone faced this error "Error: No valid counters" using type perf?

Tags: sql-server

Has anyone faced this error, `Error: No valid counters`, using `typeperf` utility while writing it to SQL database. I have tried variety of different things but every time I try to write it in SQL database using counters in a file it fails with the No valid counters error.

The command was executed in the following fashion:

```
C:\>typeperf -cf "E:\DBA\CounterCollector\counters_eg.txt" -si 15 -sc 10 -f SQL -o SQL:SQLServerDS!log5
```

The `counters_eg.txt` file contains:

```
"\\<computername>\PhysicalDisk(* *)\Avg. Disk Queue Length"
```

I am able to write in SQL database by specifying the counters individually at command prompt.

example:

```
C:\Windows\system32>typeperf -f SQL -o SQL:SQLServerDS!log4 "\\<computername>\PhysicalDisk(* *)\Avg. Disk Queue Length"
```

Note: I have replaced the server name by `<computername>`.

Comment: Related: [Typepref command gives no valid counters when running remote command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26258836/typepref-command-gives-no-valid-counters-when-running-remote-command)

Answer (score 2):

Include a double '%%', i.e.

```
typeperf "\\<remote-IP>\Process(*)\%% Processor Time" -sc 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out:

After following the example from 
https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/collecting-performance-data-into-a-sql-server-table/
I kept on getting the same error message "Error: No valid counters". The counter.txt is exactly the same like the example provided by Feodor but when I put the counter names on the command line individually, they get processed successfully. The problem I was getting was when I tried to run the entire syntax. 
Instead of using what Feodor used:
"TYPEPERF -f SQL -s ALF -cf “C:\CounterCollect\Counters.txt” -si 15 -o SQL:SQLServerDS!log1 -sc 4",
I tweaked it a little bit (after looking at the second example from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753182.aspx) and finally it WORKED! It is a matter of switching the parameters.

After following the demo by Feodor, I used this below syntax, and it worked for me. I am using SQL Server 2012 and here is the command:

`TYPEPERF -cf "C:\PerfMonCollect\Counters.txt" -si 5 -sc 4 -f SQL -o SQL:SQLdatasource!log1".`

Answer (score 1):

Your counters list may be damaged. Run **perfmon** GUI utility and make sure that you are able to see the counters in there.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your file name is correct. counters.txt NOT counters.txt.txt . show extensions then check the file name. also, you can try the RUN command and paste your target to the text file and see if it works.
I had the same issue and it drove me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error now and solved it by adding the user running typeperf to local administrators group on the servers that threw the error.

Comment: That is a bit extreme, and unsafe. You should add the user to the `Performance Log Users` group instead.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error on a server(Windows Server 2012 R2) I had admin rights on, I had to manually build performance counters and it was sorted. Here's the link https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2554336/how-to-manually-rebuild-performance-counters-for-windows-server-2008-6

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that the file should contain only file names, without `"` quote marks.

Removing all `"` from counterlist resolved the issue for me.

Comment: this should be a comment