# Typepref command gives no valid counters when running remote command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I am stuck badly into this.

I am trying to execute following batch command which runs successfully on my system present on same network as remote server,

typeperf "\192.168.1.247\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" -sc 2

But if I try to run the same command on another remote server present on same network,

typeperf "\192.168.1.241\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" -sc 2

this gives me **Error: No valid counters.**

Please let me know what could be the issue and what could be the possible solution to this.

Regards,
Suvojit

Comment: Include a double '\\', i.e. `typeperf "\\192.168.1.241\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" -sc 2`; have you tried server name instead of IP address?; does your server run Windows? Windows in English language?

Comment: Sorry, But I missed "\\" in this post. Actually I have included "\\" in my command.
Also I tried server name instead of IP address, but still  the same issue. Same problem also exist for my other servers like 192.168.1.249/192.168.1.251, but works fine for 192.168.1.247/231/230

Comment: Also 247,251,241,249 all runs Windows Server 2003,whereas 230,231,232 runs Windows Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try refreshing WMI with this command:

   `winmgmt /resyncperf & wmiadap /f`
2. Make sure that the WMI service is running, or restart it:

   `net start winmgmt`
3. Run this command to ensure that the disable key doesnt exist, or its value is 0 if it exists.

   `REG query HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\PerfProc\Performance /v "Disable Performance Counters"`
4. Try rebuilding the performance registry with the [LODCTR /R](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/lodctr) command.
5. If nothing else works, you can try to [manually rebuild Performance Counter library values](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/300956/how-to-manually-rebuild-performance-counter-library-values) as a last resort.